# An entities that create entities using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

How do you handle the case when an entity needs to create, in one of its methods, other entities? My problem is that since each individual entity doesn't have access ObjectContext object, that one with the AddToBlahs() methods, it cannot do it.

For example, having a Site model that has a UpdateLinks() method that is supposed to create Link objects belonging to that Site. The UpdateLinks() method doesn't have an ObjectContext. What do you do? Do you pass one to it, like this:

```
public void UpdateLinks(ProjectEntities db) {
    foreach (var link in FetchLinks()) {
        db.AddToLinks(link);
    }
}
```

or do you use another pattern?

Comment: Now I also have the reverse question :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097883/how-to-delete-an-asociated-object-in-entity-framework-without-having-access-to-th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the context for this.

Since `Site.UpdateLinks` is creating `Link` objects *belonging to the instance,* the instance will have associations with the new `Site`. Adding a `Link` to `Site.Links` *automatically* makes the new `Link` part of the same context (if any) as the `Site`. Likewise, when you save the `Site` the `Link` will be saved with it.

Comment: I've tried doing Links.Add(link) where Links is the LinkSet but I've got:

"Entities in 'ProjectEntities.Links' participate in the 'Sites_have_Links' relationship. 0 related 'Sites' were found. 1 'Sites' is expected."

I did set the Site relationship to "this" in the new link.

Comment: That is *not* what I suggested doing. That said, setting `Link.Site` to some site *should* make that work, if you've defined the relationship property correctly.

Comment: What I'm doing is: var link = new Link(); link.Site = this; this.Links.Add(link); and it works. How is that now what you suggested (except that maybe link.Site = this is redundant)?

Comment: I didn't understand that you had an implicit `this` in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the answer by Craig Stuntz... The Link should be attached to the context, but adding a Link to Site.Links does not attach it automatically. You need to do db.AddToLinks(link) anyway.

But answering your question, one of the best patterns for ObjectContext management is probably the UnitOfWork pattern. By using it, you can make entities "self-aware of the scope they currently belong to".
Check out this [article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/managing-entity-framework-objectcontext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-asp-net-applications.aspx) for a detailed description and implementation samples.
You can still pass the ObjectContext to the method as a parameter as you do in you example though (as a simpler implementation).

Comment: You are wrong. If one object is attached to a context and a second object is not, associating the two will attach the second object. Try it! Look at `second.EntityState` before and after making the association. You're also wrong about needing to call `AddToLinks`.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected then, thanks. And this also saved me a couple of lines of code ;)